# onPostExecute is not getting called after successful completion of doinbackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have used `Async Task` many times but I am facing this type of problem for the first time. I searched Stack Overflow but couldn't find any useful solution.

My issue is `onPostExecute` is not getting called in Async task, All operations that are in `doinbackground` are completed but control is not reaching the `onPostExecute`... not able to understand the reason.

Code:

```
public class deletedaily extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, long[]>{

    ProgressDialog pd;
    long resultdelete;
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        pd=new ProgressDialog(StockDetail.this);
        if(pd!=null){

            pd.setMessage("Deleting data.....please wait");
            pd.show();
        }
    }

    protected long[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().beginTransaction();
            resultdelete = Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().delete(st.tablename, st.column2 + "=? AND " + st.column3 + "=?", new String[] {getdailydate.toString(),stockname} );
            Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();

            new popdailydata().execute(); //here calling list view to populate after deletion
        }
        catch(Exception dailydeleteerror){}
        finally{
                Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().endTransaction();
        }
        return new long[] {resultdelete};
    }   

    protected void onPostExecute(long result){

        System.out.println("postexecute entered");
        if(pd!=null){

            pd.dismiss();
        }

        if(result!=-1){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date deleted from your portfolio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to delete ....try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

I am calling from onclick of Image buton

```
deletedailydata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    new deletedaily().execute();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please show how you start the Asynctask..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `onPostExecute(long [] result)`.

You extended your class like `AsyncTask<Void , Void, long[]>`. This means that the return value of doInBackground will be `long[]` and the parameter of onPostExecute also. As what you get in onPostExecute is the result returned by doInBackgroud the type should be the same.